# How to populate system certificates under IIS?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I need to populate system certificates. Same source code tells me the certificates count correctly when I debug it under VS. When I run the code under IIS 7.5 Windows 7, .Count always returns 0. Is there any permission problem? Why does the count return 0?

```
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store store = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My);
        store.Open(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        Response.Write("<hr>Certs count: " + store.Certificates.Count.ToString() + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS and VS debugger run under different user credentials. So IIS cannot load the certificates. Here is my workaround:

I'll make a commandline utility and [run it as user](http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2005/12/02/startprocessasuser.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) helps to load user's certificates.

P.S: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name gets the user name.